# Liquibase maps ZonedDateTime as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: java, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-maven-plugin

I am using `mvn liquibase:diff` to generate the changests with the differences between my spring entities and the database.

Everything works fine except when I am using the `ZonedDateTime` type.
`mvn liquibase:diff` generates a changeset with `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, but it should be generating a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. How can I specify that the mapping must be `ZonedDateTime → TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and `LocalDateTime → TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

P.S. I am using PosgreSQL database.
Thank you.

I am expecting that the mapping must be `ZonedDateTime → TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, and `LocalDateTime → TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

Answer (score 1):

### No, not `ZonedDateTime`

[`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is *not* defined in the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) mapping of Java classes to SQL types.

### `OffsetDateTime`

[`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) is the class to use with a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. See [JDBC 4.2 specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-eval-spec/jdbc4.2-fr-spec.pdf).

| Kind | Components | Standard SQL | PostgreSQL | Java |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moment | date, time, offset | TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE | TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE | `OffsetDateTime` |
| Not a moment | date, time | TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE | TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE | `LocalDateTime` |

You said:

> ZonedDateTime type. mvn liquibase:diff generates a changeset with TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, but it should be generating a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

No, it should not.

Only `OffsetDateTime` is mapped to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in JDBC. The other two classes that represent a specific point on the timeline are *not* mapped in JDBC: [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) & [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

The SQL Standard unfortunately used the word *time zone*, but actually meant *offset from UTC*.

Comment: I've tried using OffsetDateTime and LocalDateTime. Both times using the mvn liquibase:diff command, it still generated a TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE.